# Deploying WAR files on a shared host?

Tags: jsp, deployment

How would I go about deploying a WAR file on a shared host? Everything I read about deploying them says I put them in webapps inside the Tomcat root directory. Then go to localhost:8000. My hosting account is a shared account where I can get to my site by theIP/~MyUsername/. I don't have access to anything above the /home/MyUsername directory. Tomcat is running, and I can upload JSP files and view them. Do I just have to manually unpack the WAR file and upload the contents?

If I could get root access, how would I deploy a WAR file? If I put the file in the webapps directory, would it unpack into the MyUsername directory?

Answer (score 2):

Unzip the WAR files into the same location as you put the jsp files; it should just work.